# Background Task Execution At Regular Intervels

Tags: java, android, timer, alarmmanager

I tested my app on an Android 12 device for background task execution at regular intervals.I registered a broadcast receiver for activity recognition and on every user activity detection, I need to update the server and local database. For this, i am using a Timer to execute the task at every 5 hours

```
 public void setTimer(int Minutes) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Set Timer Starts It will Run Every " + Minutes);
        int MilliSeconds = 60000 * Minutes;
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DefaultExecutorSupplier.getInstance().forBackgroundTasks().execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            //CODE THAT YOU WANT TO EXECUTE AT GIVEN INTERVAL

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        };
        new Timer().schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, MilliSeconds);
    }
```

But it's not executing at all (In the background). Is there any other solution for regular code execution at regular intervals on Android 12?

WorkManager is not an option because of the minimum 15 min interval limitation. Sometimes our interval changed to 2 min or 5 min according to the user's activities

Comment: "WorkManager is not the option because of the minimum 15 min interval limitation" -- use `WorkManager` for longer intervals. Use a foreground service and some in-process timing solution for the shorter intervals. You used `Timer`, which may work. Personally, I prefer `ScheduledExecutorService` or something based off of a reactive framework (e.g., RxJava).

Comment: @CommonsWare You are right `WorkManager` will work for more than 15 min intervals. The foreground service will kill by system so the timer. I will see if `ScheduledExecutorService ` will work for me. Thanks